# Get column index after entering ContextMenuStrip_Click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I have a simple datagridview, and I've added a context menu strip, with one choice. This context menu strip which would normally appear if you right clicked anywhere on the control, but with this code, I've made it to show only when you right click on the column **header**.

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if ((ht.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader))
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(MousePosition);
        }
    }
}
```

**Goal :** I would like to be able to get the column index (that I right clicked and subsequently brought the context menu up) in the showToolStripMenuItem_Click event. This is the code for this event.

```
private void showToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs args = new       
        DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(ht.ColumnIndex, 0, 0, 0, new 
        MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(null, args);
}
```

Unfortunately the showToolStripMenuItem_Click event has EventArgs, instead of DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs, in which case it would be easy to get the column index: e.ColumnIndex.

What you see in the second function is I've tried to instantiate a DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs class and use it to get my index, unfortunately it the e.ColumnIndex property here always returns -1.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`CellContextMenuStripNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontextmenustripneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView`.

Create a `ContextMenuStrip` and then handle [`CellContextMenuStripNeeded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontextmenustripneeded(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and check if this is the column header, show context menu.

There you can detect the row index and column index using `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex`.

**Code**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if this is column header
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        //Show the context menu
        e.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;

        //e.ColumnIndex is the column than you right clicked on it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've already handled making sure that it only appears when the right click was on a column header, through the MouseDown event. This gets fired first. Prolem is that when I click on the context menu and go into showToolStripMenuItem_Click, I no longer have access to DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs.

Comment: No problem, Forget about mouse down and store `e.ColumnIndex` some where for example in a variable or in `Tag` of the `ContextMenuStrip` or items , ....