# copy paste and cut clicks do not exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms

Am creating a context menu programmatically as to have right click options on my datagrid. Here is my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //string fileExcel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillCari();
        FillCombo();
        ContextMenuStrip mnu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem mnuCopy = new ToolStripMenuItem("Copy");
        ToolStripMenuItem mnuCut = new ToolStripMenuItem("Cut");
        ToolStripMenuItem mnuPaste = new ToolStripMenuItem("Paste");
        //Assign event handlers
        mnuCopy.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCopy_Click);
        mnuCut.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCut_Click);
        mnuPaste.Click += new EventHandler(mnuPaste_Click);
        //Add to main context menu
        mnu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { mnuCopy, mnuCut, mnuPaste });
        //Assign to datagridview
        dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = mnu;


    }
```

This particular block I keep getting the error that it does not exist in current context. Any idea why?

```
mnuCopy.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCopy_Click);
        mnuCut.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCut_Click);
        mnuPaste.Click += new EventHandler(mnuPaste_Click);
```

Updated question:I created the strips from the context menu but not sur ehow to implement the copy commands.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //string fileExcel;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillCari();
        FillCombo();
        ContextMenuStrip mnu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        dataGridView3.ContextMenuStrip = mnu;
    }


private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Post the *exact* error. " it does not exist in current context." doesn't help at all

Comment: those need to be declared as members, not local variable.s

Comment: PS. Why are you modifying the *constructor*? The form doesn't even exist until the constructor exits successfully. Is this why you added `InitializeComponent`, because you kept getting errors?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `The name 'mnuCopy_Click' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: You should have event handler methods like this `private void mnuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ /* Do something */ }`

Comment: Why are you adding all of these items and events here rather than doing them in the designer?

Comment: @Jevon did you create these methods? They won't create themselves. I suggest you use the forms designer until you understand how controls and event handlers work, and how you can extend a form without breaking it

Comment: I have updated my code. I've assigned it to my datagrid3, what am I doing wrong? still not showing. @RezaAghaei

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated my code. I've assigned it to my datagrid3, what am I doing wrong? still not showing.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't contain any menu item. You should add some menu item, like the first revision of question. Also it's completely better and recommended to use designer for such task, to know why, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801463/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yeah designer is what am using now. I had clicked the strips

Comment: By the way @Jevon it's not good to change the question completely and make it a new one. This way the comments and answers seems to be nonsense for future readers. Now if you take a look at the question it's not clear what is the problem and why someone posted a piece of code that you also have in the question yourself.

Comment: So I should type my updated question in  the edits? @RezaAghaei

Comment: @RezaAghaei i edited and put updated question

Comment: As I mentioned in comments your context menu strip `mnu` which you set as `ContextMenuStrip` of `DataGridView` doesn't contain any item. I know you added another ContextMenuStrip at design time and added some menu items, but you didn't set that one as `ContextMenuStrip` of your `DataGridView`. You can set that one as `ContextMenuStrip` of `DataGridView` using `Designer`. You don't need writing even a single line of code to add a `ContextMenuStrip` to `DataGridView`. The code just should be written for content of event handlers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128468/discussion-between-jevon-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: By the way, you will find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34095704/3110834) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had figured it out for awhile now. Hopefully it helps anyone in the future. Keep in mind after creating your contextMenuStrip and adding a "copy" field to the strip you will then bind it to the dataGridView. This is done by going into properties of the context menu and looking for the dataGridView name and bind it to it. After that open the click event in properties on the contextMenu and add this code in it:

```
 private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView3.Select();
        DataObject o = dataGridView3.GetClipboardContent();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(o);
    }
```

You should now have your right click copy button working.

Answer (score 0):

> For the click event you need event handlers:

```
  // event click
  mnuCopy.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCopy_Click);
  mnuCut.Click += new EventHandler(mnuCut_Click);
  mnuPaste.Click += new EventHandler(mnuPaste_Click);

  // event handler method
  void mnuPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // paste logic
  }
  void mnuCut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // cut logic
  }
  void mnuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // copy logic
  }
```